# How to save an image from collection view to document directory and then retrieve it in the same cell in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, collectionview

I am creating an application where users upload images to a collection view cell by tapping on the image. I am able to post the image to the desired cell, but when the app closes it disappears.

I have made the app save one image, but I am having trouble assigning the images to their own cells. As such, I get situations where all the cells are the last uploaded image.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuse_cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    self.currentCellBeingEdited = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell?
    cell.backgroundColor = IMColors.flatGrey

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var imageData = defaults.data(forKey: "name")
    if let imageData = imageData {
        let thumbnailImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        cell.image.image = thumbnailImage
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.currentCellBeingEdited = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell?
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    print(indexPath.row)
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    self.currentCellBeingEdited?.image.image = pickedImage
    self.currentCellBeingEdited = nil

    let dataForImage = pickedImage
    let data: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(dataForImage!, 1.0)! as NSData
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var imageForCell = String(describing: currentCellBeingEdited)
    defaults.set(data, forKey: "name")

}
```